How to Conditionally Hide Widgets Based on User Roles in Thingsboard?
I'm working with Thingsboard and need some assistance with controlling the visibility of widgets based on user roles or specific conditions. Specifically, I want to enable or disable the visibility of certain widgets to particular users. For example, I want only certain users to see a widget that directs to another state with more detailed information about users.( It could be that I group the user and add New Telemetry such as person is true , or add this Telemetry for each user  and have an access to this variable from Widget to check the telemetry is true or false )
I've tried implementing this using the "Show/Hide action" function, but I'm unsure how to configure it properly within Thingsboard. Here’s an image illustrating my current setup: 
Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Any pointers on configuring the function to selectively show or hide widgets based on user roles would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!
